# Simulating Thread failure in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I'm working on something as part of a college assignment, part of what's being asked is the simulation of thread failures. for context, I'm using the executor service from the Java SE

I've looked around SO and Google a bit but haven't been able to find anything concrete or specific on doing something like that.

Does anyone know of or have any good sources for information or guidance on how to approach doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by _thread failures_?

Comment: You mean your `Runnable` or `Callable` should throw an exception while executing is action?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis My apologies, should've been clearer. How I interpret the question is that I need to somehow have a a task that's being done in the thread pool to have a random chance of failing.

To further clarify, this is what I've been given
"Simulate thread failure and implement an appropriate monitoring and recovery mechanism."

Also, I'm not looking for someone to do my work, just ideas or information on it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Runnable, I would assume.

Comment: Again, ***WHAT DO YOU MEAN BY "FAILURE"***

Comment: We still need to know what "failing" means. Throws an exception, perhaps?

Comment: `somehow have a a task that's being done in the thread pool to have a random chance of failing.` He just wants a race condition. That should be easy

Comment: @Cruncher by this sentence: *Simulate thread failure and implement an appropriate monitoring and recovery mechanism.* I don't think OP refers to a race condition.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information, but that's what I was asked and all I have. I know little on the topic, searched for information and couldn't find any.

Comment: Since the only thing I can come up with your non-defined *thread failure*, I guess you can create a class `DummyThreadFailure` class that implements `Runnable` (or `Callable`, depending which you use) and throws a `new RuntimeException("Dummy thread failure.")`

Comment: I think what you mean is to simulate failures by timing out the thread randomly or simply returning null from a Callable object wrapped in a FutureTask. This would be the easiest way to simulate failures in a thread pool. Eg. `public class FailThread implements Callable<FailThread>{ @Override public boolean call() { if(Math.random() <= 0.1){return false;} }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test how threads "fail" when they encounter an exception you can implement a `Runnable` which you can command to fail:

```
public class FailingRunnable implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean doFail = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!doFail && ! Thread.interrupted())
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("failed");
    }

    public void failOnNextOccasion() {
        doFail = true;
    }

}
```

You must keep a reference to the runnable after you add it to the executor and then at any given time call the method `failOnNextOccasion()` of your runnable. Like this:

```
    ExecutorService execSrv = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    FailingRunnable one = new FailingRunnable();
    FailingRunnable two = new FailingRunnable();

    execSrv.submit(one);
    execSrv.submit(two);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    one.failOnNextOccasion();
    two.failOnNextOccasion();
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more complicated thread failing with a not so obvious bug:

```
public class Test {

  static class FailerThread implements Runnable {

    final Object[] objects;
    final Random random;
    final int number;

    public FailerThread(final Object[] objects, final int number) {
      this.objects = objects;
      this.random = new Random();
      this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      final boolean isWriter = number % 2 == 0;
      int index = random.nextInt(objects.length);
      try {
        while (Thread.interrupted() == false) {
          synchronized (objects) {
            if (isWriter) {
              while (objects[index] == null) {
                System.out.println(number + ": Index " + index + " is null, waiting...");
                objects.wait();
              }
              for (int copyIndex = 0; copyIndex < objects.length; ++copyIndex) {
                if (objects[copyIndex] == null) {
                  objects[copyIndex] = this.objects[index];
                }
              }
              objects.notifyAll();
            } else {
              objects[index] = null;
            }
          }

          ++index;
          if (index >= objects.length) {
            index = 0;
          }
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final Object[] objects = new Object[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
      objects[i] = new Object();
    }

    final int NUM_THREADS = 32;
    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
      executor.execute(new FailerThread(objects, i));
    }
  }
}
```

It should fail immediately, however the reason for this is everything but trivial.

Comment: You are checking for the interrupted flag inside a try-block for an InterruptedException with an empty catch-block. Who will set the interrupted flag?